# Multiple joins gives sql statement not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

here is my query:

```
select p1.driver_id, p1.name, o1.driver_id, o1.license, part.license, part.amount 
from
    (person p1 full outer join owns o1 on p1.driver_id = o1.driver_id) and
    (Participated part full outer join ol on part.license = o1.license)
```

I get the sql statement not properly ended error.  I just want to build the table as part of my process of solving a more complicated problem.

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` is going to give you results where `Owns` or `Participated` has a row, but `Person` does not.  Given that I doubt your data actually looks like that, you probably really want a regular `INNER JOIN` instead (except maybe a `LEFT JOIN` to `Participated`).  What is it you're trying to report on?

Answer (score 1):

That is not how you define the relations in the `FROM` part. Try the following:

```
select p1.driver_id, p1.name, o1.driver_id, o1.license, part.license, part.amount 
from
    person p1
    full outer join owns o1 on p1.driver_id = o1.driver_id
    full outer join Participated part on part.license = o1.license;
```

Notes:

- After `FROM` you can list some relations (comma separated), and a relation can also be a `a FULL OUTER JOIN b ON ...` form as you correctly wrote.
- You can also chain these (with brackets if you prefer) as

  ```
  a FULL OUTER JOIN b ON ... FULL OUTER JOIN c ON ...
  ```
- You can *not* use `AND` to connect relations, that is only used to connect conditions.
- You can bracket a statement to form a subquery, such as

  ```
  (SELECT * FROM a FULL OUTER JOIN b ON ...) AS t
  ```

  but note t hat you need the `SELECT *` at the beginning to turn it into a relation and in most systems you need an alias after (`t` in the example).

Comment: Actually, it's preferable to _not_ use the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause), as it's officially deprecated, and is difficult to do certain types of joins correctly (usually, `OUTER` joins...)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse agreed, if a `JOIN` operator describes what you need then it is always clearer than implicit. Even better syntax might be `JOIN USING (driver_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.driver_id, p1.name, o1.driver_id, o1.license, part.license, part.amount 
FROM person p1 
     FULL OUTER JOIN owns o1 
     ON p1.driver_id = o1.driver_id     
     FULL OUTER JOIN Participated part 
     ON part.license = o1.license
```